# Make backspace(+?) remove a level of indentation in ReST mode

Tags: key-bindings, indentation

I often find myself in the situation where ReST-mode has correctly identified that my last line can be followed by an idented line, but I want to continue on the next higher level of indentation.

How do I make backspace (or C-backspace or whatever) delete a single level of indentation when on a line with only whitespace before the cursor?

For example, from (█ is the cursor)

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
              █
```

I want to get to

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   █
```

by pressing backspace once. The 11 spaces should be deleted. What do I need to do? I know python-mode has functionality like this.